# How to flatten JSON in Typescript or angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have this json I need to format it in Typescript or java script. what would be better way to do.

```
var data = {
"value 1" : [
    {
        type : String,
        Dicription : "abc"
    },
    {
        type : int,
        Dicription : "xyz"
    },
    {
        type : String,
        Dicription : "pqr"
    },
    ]
"value 2" : [
    {
        type : String,
        Dicription : "abc"
    }
    ]
"value 3" : [
    {
        type : String,
        Dicription : "abc"
    },
    {
        type : int,
        Dicription : "xyz"
    }
}
```

Need Output like this

```
{
    {
       value : value1,
       type : String,
       Description : "abc"
    },
    {
       value : value1,
       type : int,
       Dicription : "xyz"
    },
    {
       value : value1,
       type : String,
       Dicription : "pqr"
    },
    {
        value : value2,
        type : String,
        Description : "abc"
    },
    {
        value : value3,
        type : String,
        Description : "abc"
    },
    {   value : value3,
        type : int,
        Description : "xyz"
    }
}
```

I tried

```
var new = [];
Var values = Object.keys(data)
values.ForEach(Function(value){

new.push({
'value' : value })

});
```

and iterate it, but could not get desired output. I tried to flatten this but I got objects like {value : value , { type: String ,Description : abc}}
What should I do to solve it

Comment: Your input and output do not add up. You have space in each `value 1`, `value 2` etc inputs, and no space in the output example. And you do not explain such a data mutation.

Comment: I have multiple values in a list, I just need to add one more field. I need to display value1 , data type and description in a table. fo this I thought I should manipulate json and then display.

Comment: You can not have an object of objects. Please edit your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the keys and values separately and iterate though first object and create another object and push values in it.

So my solution for the problem is

````
var keys = Object.keys(data);
var values = Object.values(data);
var length = Object.values(data).length;
keys.ForEach(function (key, index){
values.ForEach(function (obj, i) {
if(index == i){
   var innerValue = Object.values(obj);
   for(i=0 ; i<=innerValue.length; i++)
   {
    new.push({
           'value: key,
           'type': innerValue[i].type,
           'Description': innerValue[i].abc,
           });
    }
}
});
});```
````

Answer (score 2):

Convert the object to an an array using `Object.entries()`, and then flat map the entries to an array of objects:

```
const result = Object.entries(data) // get the entries of the object
  .flatMap(([value, arr]) =>  // map and flatten the sub-arrays
    arr.map(o => ({ // map each sub-array and combine with the value
      value,
      ...o
    }))
  )
```